# Can't draw figures in Java instantly

Tags: java, draw

Good day!
I develop program client-server and met one problem and i really don't know how to solve it.

So, i have few buttons. When button clicks then info sends to the server, server does some work and sends result. Listener of button receives that and then call method of other class which must draw the result on screen.

So, here is problem. Server sends me few results and program must draw it instantly. But it doesn't do that! It waits till all messages will come and ONLY then draws result.

So i want to know how to draw result on the screen instantly!

Code:
Listener of Button:

```
public class ShowFrame extends JFrame
{
    startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
       {
            try 
            {
                messageToServer.println("Start");

                while( true )
                {
                    fserver = answerOfServer.readLine(); //Get result from server

                    if ( fserver.equals("Finish") )
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    if( fserver.equals("Busy 1") )
                    {
                        ShowFrame.this.stuff.setBusy( 1 );
                    }
                    if( fserver.equals("Busy 2") )
                    {
                        ShowFrame.this.stuff.setBusy( 2 );
                    }
                    //...Same code


                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ShowFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }

    DrawStuff stuff = new DrawStuff();
    //...
}
```

Class which draw result on the screen:

```
public class DrawStuff extends JComponent
{

public DrawStuff()
{
    s1 = false;
    s2 = false;
    s3 = false;
    s4_1 = false;
    s4_2 = false;
    s4_3 = false;
}

@Override
public void paintComponent( Graphics g )
{
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    //...
        if ( s1 )                     
        {
                g2.draw(line1_of_P1);
                g2.draw(line2_of_P1);
        }
        //...
 }

public void setBusy( int i ) //If such id found then figure will be drawn by prog.
{
    if      ( i == 1 )
    {
        s1   = true;
    }
    else if ( i == 2 )
    {
        s2   = true;
    }
    else if ( i == 3 )
    {
        s3   = true;
    }
    else if ( i == 4 )
    {
        s4_1 = true;
    }
    else if ( i == 5 )
    {
        s4_2 = true;
    }
    else if ( i == 6 )
    {
        s4_3 = true;
    }
    this.repaint(); //DOESN'T WORK AS IT MUST!

}
//...
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You execute reading in event dispatch thread and it's not good. You should do it in separate thread (because it is long running task). See http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute the actual actions within a separate thread so the event dispatch thread can keep on running (it needs to be running to paint the screen). You can create and start a new thread running by using the following:

```
    Thread newThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
      // put your actions to perform in here
    }});

    newThread.start();
```

Call this in your action listener.

Comment: Bear in mind also that you must create a new Runnable and post that back to the event dispatch thread (SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable r)) *within the created thread* to modify the UI state again.

Comment: @Chris: I'm not sure you do. Since you want it to run on the EDT, which is somewhat special, you could just call a method that updates the UI state using SwingUtilities.invokeLater(). This does require you to take a Runnable object, but you can create it on the fly.

Comment: When you execute a new thread within that runnable which is running on the EDT as part of the dispatch mechanism, the newly-created runnable is no longer executing on the EDT, but in a separate thread. That's what I meant :)

Comment: Yes, that's true. But you can force execution to happen on the EDT when you use SwingUtilities.invokeLater. (I mean, from the second thread you execute). LOL... this is getting confusing.

Comment: Oh, you're right. You can do an invokeLater call inside the EDT. But not an invokeAndWait. But he wants to do blocking actions within the newly created thread, so he'd have to do invokeLater in that.

Comment: Edited to remove the invokeAndWait. Thanks for correcting me.